# Not able to run protractor tests

Tags: selenium, protractor

I've executed `npm install -g protractor` and also updated the drivers via the `webdriver-manager update` command.

After executing `webdriver-manager start` the server boots up, but it gives me some kind of strange output in the beginning. I am suspecting this error to cause my main error- not to be able to execute tests.

```
C:\xxx>webdriver-manager start
{ Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=write EPROTO 10940:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:openssl\ssl\record\ssl3_record.c:252:

    at ClientRequest.onError (xx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\tunnel-agent\index.js:177:17)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:392:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at onwriteError (_stream_writable.js:431:12)
    at onwrite (_stream_writable.js:456:5)
    at _destroy (internal/streams/destroy.js:40:7)
    at TLSSocket.Socket._destroy (net.js:617:3)
    at TLSSocket.destroy (internal/streams/destroy.js:32:8) code: 'ECONNRESET' }
[10:41:24] I/start - java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=C:\xx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\geckodriver-v0.26.0.exe -jar C:\xx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -port 4444
[10:41:24] I/start - seleniumProcess.pid: 17424
10:41:24.618 INFO [GridLauncherV3.parse] - Selenium server version: 3.141.59, revision: e82be7d358
10:41:24.701 INFO [GridLauncherV3.lambda$buildLaunchers$3] - Launching a standalone Selenium Server on port 4444
2020-04-29 10:41:24.746:INFO::main: Logging initialized @348ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
10:41:24.966 INFO [WebDriverServlet.<init>] - Initialising WebDriverServlet
10:41:25.298 INFO [SeleniumServer.boot] - Selenium Server is up and running on port 4444
```

After creating a basic test then and executing `protractor conf.js`, I get the error that the ChromeDriverService couldn't be created.

```
C:\Users\Q379281\Desktop\test>protractor conf.js
[10:44:05] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[10:44:05] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[10:44:06] E/launcher - Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'LW05813246', ip: '10.131.89.227', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_251'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
[10:44:06] E/launcher - SessionNotCreatedError: Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'LW05813246', ip: '10.131.89.227', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_251'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (C:\Users\Q379281\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:546:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (C:\Users\Q379281\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:509:13)
    at doSend.then.response (C:\Users\Q379281\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:441:30)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
```

What may be interesting is that I'm sitting behind a proxy and had to install/update the drivers with the `--proxy` option. Furthermore, I'm also not able to create a new session manually in the hub `http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/`.

Comment: for the  `webdriver-manager start` error, please try specify proxy like execute `update`.  If you not specify the driver version for start cmd, webdriver-manager will query the latest version from internet and skip download if your local have. So it need internet access when not tell the version to use explicitly for start cmd.

Comment: If above approach fix the start issue,  the second issue for creating session is not related to the start issue.  It's mostly due to your chrome browser is not compatible with the chrome webdriver.  If so please find out the compatible chrome webdriver version and specify the chrome webdriver version in webdriver-manage update and start cmd.